# Looping through JSON in a Selmer template

Tags: clojure, luminus, selmer

I`m making simple quiz game and want to store the questions in a JSON file like so:

```
{"questions":
    [  
      {  
         "question":"2+2 ?",
         "answer_A":1,
         "answer_B":2,
         "answer_C":3,
         "answer_D":4,
         "correct_answer":4
      },
      {  
         "question":"2+3?",
         "answer_A":1,
         "answer_B":2,
         "answer_C":3,
         "answer_D":5,
         "correct_answer":5
      }    
  ] }
```

This is code to load it from file:

```
defn json-page []
(layout/render
    "json.html" {:file (parse-string (slurp "path/to/file"))}))
```

parse-string return a string, so I cannot loop over it to display every element. How can I do this? I know the syntax `({% for question in file %})`, but I don't know how to access nested elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Reddit for answer :

```
(defn json-page []
    (layout/render
        "json.html" {:file (parse-string (slurp "path/to/file") true)}))
```

The answer was to add true as a parameter for `parse-string` to keywordize the json maps. After this I can loop over json :

```
{% for question in file.questions %}
        <p>{{ question.question }}.</p>
        {{ question.answer_A}}
        {{ question.answer_B}}
        {{ question.answer_C}}
        {{ question.answer_D}}
 {% endfor %}
```